# jQuery.find() doesn't work inside html variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very simple problem and keep finding answers to similar questions with more complexity.  I am trying to replace image links in loaded html and decided that the best is to read the html into a string variable `loadedHTML` using `.get()`, like this:

```
$.get(loadURL, function(loadedHTML) {
    myFunction(loadedHTML);
}, 'html');
```

In myFunction, I want to make some changes to the loaded html and eventually return it.  I can't get `.find()` to work.  Here is what that code looks like:

```
function myFunction( html ) {
    var $html = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
    console.log( "$html.html() = " + $html.html()); // works!
    $html.find("img", function() {
        console.log("found an image"); // doesn't work :(
    });
}
```

I am killing myself with something that is probably really simply.  Let me know how I am dumb please...

Comment: find() doesn't have a callback, but might be something worth extending

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost sure that you cannot use `find` in the way that you have.

Try something like:

```
var $foundImages = $html.find("img");
console.log($foundImages.length);
```

Which would, in theory, output the number of images that were found.

Comment: The problem is that I need to edit those elements' attributes, not just see how many there are.

Comment: Then use $.each() to go through each one.

Answer (score 1):

The find method doesn't have a second parameter:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

You should try this:

```
function myFunction( html ) {
    var $html = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
    console.log( "$html.html() = " + $html.html()); // works!
    console.log($html.find("img"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign id to your div tag .

like below,

```
 var $html = $("<div id='placeholder'>" + html + "</div>");
```

and find img with it like below,

```
$("#placeholder").find("img", function() {
    console.log("found an image"); // doesn't work :(
});
```

your resultant code,

```
function myFunction( html ) {
var $html = $("<div id='placeholder'>" + html + "</div>");
console.log( "$html.html() = " + $html.html()); // works!
$("#placeholder").find("img", function() {
    console.log("found an image"); // doesn't work :(
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**`.find()`** didn't have callback function in jquery. it have parameter for `selectors,elements,jqueryObject` only.you have to check with length or condition like this

```
if($html.find("img").length > 0){

      // do stuff here
}
```

or

```
  if($html.has("img")){

       // do stuff here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.filter()`:

```
var found = $html.find("img").filter(function() {
    return this;
});
console.log(found);
```

or make an array out of it with `.map()`:

```
var found = $html.find("img").map(function() {
    return this;
}).get(); // use get() method here to get the values in array
console.log(found.length); // would give you the length of array created.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't have a callback but you can extend jQuery to do what you want:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    findEach: function (selector, callback) {
        var found = this.find(selector);

        if (typeof callback == 'function' && found.length > 0) {
            found.each(callback);
        }
        return found;
    }
});
```

Then use like you expect:

```
$html.findEach("img", function(key, value) {//will run for each image
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this);
});
```